# Cordova PushNotification in iOS is not getting registered

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I saw many solutions. But none of them helped me.

My code

```
 //push notification initialization and registration. 
if (!$window.PushNotification) {
    return;
}
var push = $window.PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "xxxx"
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false'
    },
    windows: {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    alert('push registration ' + data.registrationId);
    $rootScope.registrationId = data.registrationId;
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    alert('on notification');
    console.log(data.message);
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
});
```

I have included certificate.p12 and javapns-jdk16.jar in my project.

PushNotification is enabled and downloaded the certificate.

I'm getting the alert asking whether to allow push notification or not. But push.register call is never invoked.

I'm using xcode 8.1 version, cordova-ios 4.1.0 and plugin version 1.8.0

I want to use similar code for both ios and android push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

> As per plugin documentation it Requires **cordova-ios version: 4.3.0**, so try upgrading your ios version.
>   for reference see here : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md

Comment: I'm using plugin 1.8.0 which requires 4.1.0